# mapreduce job failes on hadoop cluster with subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, mrjob

I have a Hadoop 3.2.2 Cluster with 1 namenode/resourceManager and 3 datanodes/NodeManagers.

this is my yarn-site config

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>bd-1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

When I run the example job

`python mr_word_count.py -r hadoop -v hdfs:///user/hduser/testme.txt`

I have this error

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
```

What have I done so far:

- job runs local python `python mr_word_count.py testme.txt`
- add `#!/usr/bin/python` and  `# -*-coding:utf-8 -*` to the script head
- chmod a+x mr_word_count.px
- start master as single node instance and then the job works!
- checkted log in webUI, there is no other information to find

I can define python bin in .mrjob.conf but then the error code changes to 126

in the Console I see `map 100% reduce 100%`
In the WebUI I also see that the Job is processing, CPU and Memory is consumed by the job.

I'm googling and reading stackoverflow/haddop documentation now since 4 Days for many many hours without a result. any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to install mr_job on all nodes...

run this on all nodes fixed the problem:
`pip3 install MRJob`